# Array error in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

```
Dim scene(1 To 2) As String
Dim currentsheet As String
scene(1) = "Good"
scene(2) = "Better"
currentsheet = scene(Worksheets("Input").Cells(j, 1))
```

`j` variable keeps on changing but the first column of **Input** sheet only has vales of 1 or 2 so at each row of `currentsheet` there should be either be a value of `"Good"` if `Worksheets("Input").Cells(j, 1)= 1` or `"Better"` if `Worksheets("Input").Cells(j, 1)=2`

This gives me a type mismatch and I am not able to find out the error as I have already declared both `scene` array and `currentsheet`  as string.

Comment: what value did you assign to your variable j?

Comment: Are you sure that Worksheets("Input").Cells(j, 1) is always 1 or 2

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure the 1s and 2s in the worksheet are not numbers stored as text?

Comment: @Sorceri - J is to loop through all the rows of input sheets, but the first column always have values as 1 or 2 , so value of J doesn't matter.

Comment: Try actually specifying which property you want from the cell, for example `.Cells(j, 1).Text`

Comment: @Meesha if j= 0 then it will error as there are no cells at index 0 in excel.  I dont see where you gave j a value so by default j= 0.  Hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
currentsheet = scene(CInt(Worksheets("Input").Cells(j, 1).Value2))
```

If your cell really does just have "1" or "2" then it shouldn't make a difference, but the index of your array is defined by an integer value - so casting the contents of the cell to an integer should assist.